# Can I remove seasonal autocorrelation through aggregation?

Tags: autocorrelation, aggregation

I have monthly time series data and there is autocorrelation? I can solve for this using lagged dependent variables and other methods and other models, then aggregate into annual terms. However, I need to summarize my forecast results into annual terms. So I am wondering whether I aggregate the data first, which seems to remove seasonality and autocorrelation and use an annual time series model instead?

I understand I will lose information but is there any problem statistically with running regressions on an annual basis rather than a monthly basis?

Comment: I don't think there is an inherent problem with using yearly data instead of monthly; but you indeed lose information, so you rarely want to do that.

Comment: Yes I understand. I ended up doing both way and it proved to be fruitful exercise. My final method was to use lags and aggregating the monthly data.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using monthly data and then accumulating the forecasts to an annual level . The forecast uncertainty for the sum can be computed from the individual monthly uncertainties taking into account the covariance structure. By summing the series to an annual level you  remove the seasonal autocorrelation and the period to period autocorrelation. The autocorrelation of the annual series may still exist depending on the data.